# Exception when trying to make bulk insert in xamarin app with sqlite

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, sqlite-net

I developed code to get the Json sent from my rest service.

I receive and threat the code and generate the sql insert statement.

I got this error:

```
[0:] SQLite.SQLiteException: Constraint
  at SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery () [0x000ca] in <84b9c9e630fa45bd8ac799333976ebbf>:0 
  at GSAN_Mobile.Repository.GsanMobileRepository`1+<>c__DisplayClass9_1[T].<BulkInsert>b__0 (Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken register) [0x0002c] in D:\Projetos\Gsan\mobile\front\GSAN_Mobile\GSAN_Mobile\GSAN_Mobile\Repository\GsanMobileRepository.cs:185 
  at System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T].ForEach (System.Action`1[T] action) [0x0001e] in <6de48997d0c0445dbea8d4d83492d8c6>:0 
  at GSAN_Mobile.Repository.GsanMobileRepository`1[T].BulkInsert (Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray array, System.String tableName) [0x00062] in D:\Projetos\Gsan\mobile\front\GSAN_Mobile\GSAN_Mobile\GSAN_Mobile\Repository\GsanMobileRepository.cs:180
```

My Bulk Insert Method

```
public void BulkInsert(JArray array, string tableName = "")
{
    try
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tableName))
        {
            Type typeParameterType = typeof(T);
            tableName = typeParameterType.Name;
        }

        using (SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(DataBaseUtil.GetDataBasePath()))
        {
            connection.BeginTransaction();

            array.ToList().ForEach(register =>
            {
                string sql = DataBaseUtil.GenerateInsertStatement(register, tableName);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(sql);
                var command = connection.CreateCommand(sql);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            });

            connection.Commit();
            DataBaseUtil.CloseConnection(connection);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        LogUtil.WriteLog(e);
    }
}
```

My utils methods

```
public static string GenerateInsertStatement(JToken register, string tableName)
{
    var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(register.ToString());
    string columns = string.Join(",", data.Keys.ToList());
    string values = string.Join(",", data.Values.Select(v => string.Format(@"'{0}'", v.Trim())));
    return string.Format("INSERT INTO {0} ({1}) VALUES ({2}); ", tableName, columns, values);
}

public static void CloseConnection(SQLiteConnection connection)
{
    connection.Dispose();
    connection.Close();
}
```

And my ViewModel class

This is the method who I call when start to syncronize

```
private async Task RegistrarDados()
{
    try
    {
        _logs.Add("Realizando o Download: ");

        GenerateAtendimentoMotivosEncerramento();
        GenerateHidrometrosLocalInstalacao();
        GenerateHidrometrosProtecao();
        GenerateFuncionarios();
        GenerateGrupoFaturamento();
        GenerateLigacaoAguaSituacoes();
        GenerateLigacaoEsgotoSituacoes();
        GenerateServicosTipo();
        GenerateSistemParametros();
        GenerateOrdensServico();
        //GenerateContas();

        int contador = _ordemServicoRepository.Count<OrdemServico>();

        _logs.Add("Sincronização encerrada com sucesso!");
        await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Atenção", "Foram importados " + contador + " Ordens de Serviços!", "OK");
        PodeSincronizar = true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        LogUtil.WriteLog(e);
    }
}
```

And this is method where the error happens

```
private async void GenerateOrdensServico()
{
    try
    {
        _logs.Add("ORDENS DE SERVIÇO");

        int? records = await _ordemServicoRest.GetCount();
        int? limit = _sistemaParametroRepository.GetTamanhoPaginaSincMobile();
        int? pages = (records / limit);

        for (int i = 0; i <= pages; i++)
        {
            JArray ordensServico = await _ordemServicoRest.GetAllInJsonFormatPaginated(DataBaseUtil.GetPagination(i, limit.Value));

            if (ordensServico == null)
            {
                _logs.Add("Não Contem O.S de Corte para importar!");
                await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Atenção", "Não tem O.S para importar!", "OK");
                continue;
            }

            _ordemServicoRepository.BulkInsert(ordensServico);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        LogUtil.WriteLog(e);
    }
}
```

I received paginated date because there are 8500 registers, sometimes don´t happen the error, but in the other, I don´t uderstant the erro.

And my model class

```
[Serializable]
public class Persistent
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    [PrimaryKey]
    [NotNull]
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int? Id { get; set; }
}

[Table("OrdemServico")]
public class OrdemServico : Persistent
{

    [JsonProperty("situacaoOS")]
    public int? SituacaoOS { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("idServicoTipo")]
    public int? IdServicoTipo { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("dataGeracao")]
    public string DataGeracao { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("idRegistroAtendimento")]
    public int? IdRegistroAtendimento { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("idgrupo")]
    public int? IdGrupo { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("matriculaCliente")]
    public int? MatriculaCliente { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("nomeCliente")]
    public string NomeCliente { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("tipoLogradouro")]
    public string TipoLogradouro { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("logradouro")]
    public string Logradouro { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("numeroImovel")]
    public int? NumeroImovel { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("numeroCep")]
    public int? NumeroCep { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("bairro")]
    public string Bairro { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("numeroHidrometro")]
    public string NumeroHidrometro { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("idHidrometroProtecao")]
    public int? IdHidrometroProtecao { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("idHidrometroLocalInstalacao")]
    public int? IdHidrometroLocalInstalacao { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("imovel")]
    public int? Imovel { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ligacaoAguaSituacao")]
    public int? LigacaoAguaSituacao { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ligacaoEsgotoSituacao")]
    public int? LigacaoEsgotoSituacao { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("sincronizada")]
    public int? Sincronizada { get; set; }
}
```

I sent almost the time the Id, when has
My API not throw exception.

Answer (score 0):

The `SQLite.SQLiteException: Constraint` exception and the fact that it's randomly occurring is key. You are violating a table constraint somewhere.

Your SQLite table is expecting a value that it's not receiving. For example, if one of your data fields is marked "NOT NULL" in the table and a field in your data is NULL, that constraint will fail and you will receive the exception.

You need to determine which fields have constraints and then handle the received data to ensure constraint integrity. Convert null `TEXT` values to `String.Empty` or `null` INTEGER fields from `null` to 0 if the table has a `NOT NULL` constraint. You will have to look at the set constraints in the data structure.

With that said you should really look into parameterized queries. Your current `INSERT` statement is just asking for trouble as it's vulnerable to injection. For example, if one of the `value` strings contains a comma, it can break your statement because SQLite doesn't know `value` is just a value and just treats it as part of the query commands. Parameters fix this. This could also, be what is causing your issue if you are correctly following your table constaints.

Here's a small example of how your queries should be built instead using parameters.

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO MyTable (CompanyName, Address) VALUES (@Name, @Address)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyName", myCompanyNameString);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", myAddressString);
```

Since my dynamic query values are parameterized, I can make my values have special characters or statements like "DROP TABLE" and it will be handled correctly and protect from injection attack or exceptions from query breaking characters or words.

Comment: I dont know why but my sqlite doesnt have Parameters method

Comment: Are you using `System.Data.SQLite`? If so it should be available in the `SqliteCommand` object. That's strange if it's not there.

Comment: I´m using `SQLiteNetExtensions` and `sqlite-net-pcl` for Xamarin.

Comment: You may be able to use `cmd.Bind("@CompanyName", myCompanyNameString)` instead.